# Improve Django intermediary tables

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys, data-modeling

I'm working on a Django app that contains the following structure:

There are `Checklist`s consisting of one or more `ChecklistItem`s. We want to assign however many checklists as we want to a `Job`, and fill these Job-Checklist's questions.

An example would be to create a Checklist containing `ChecklistItem`s:

- "How are you?"
- "What is your name?"

So, each `ChecklistItem` is just a question in a checklist.

This means now we can use this `Checklist` that consists of 2 `ChecklistItem`s in any job and fill it out after assigning it.
We create Job #1, and assign it this Checklist #1, create Job #2 and assign it Checklist #1 also. Same checklist to be answered in two different jobs. Whoever's working on that particular job will then fill the checklist out according to them.

The way we first approached this was with `Job` and `Checklist` being connected by a `JobChecklist` intermediary table, and `JobChecklistItemAnswer`s being assigned to each answered checklist item (question).

```py
class Checklist(models.Model):
    """A class to represent a checklist."""

    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=150)

class ChecklistItem(models.Model):
    """A class to represent an item of a checklist."""
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(Checklist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(_("question"), max_length=200)

    
class Job(models.Model):
    """A class to represent a job."""
    checklists = models.ManyToManyField(Checklist, through="JobChecklist")


class JobChecklist(models.Model):
    """A class to represent the intermediary relation of a checklist belonging
    to a job."""

    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(Checklist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class JobChecklistItemAnswer(models.Model):
    """A class to represent the relation of a checklist item's answer belonging
    to a job's checklist."""

    job_checklist = models.ForeignKey(JobChecklist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    checklist_item = models.ForeignKey(ChecklistItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.BooleanField(_("answer"), null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        if (
            self.checklist_item
            not in self.job_checklist.checklist.checklistitem_set.all()
        ):
            raise FieldError(
                _(
                    "ChecklistItem #{} doesn't belong to {} checklist".format(
                        self.checklist_item.id, self.job_checklist.checklist
                    )
                )
            )
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see from the `JobChecklistItemAnswer` relation, we had to monkey patch the save method to make sure the answer belongs to that particular checklist item (question).
We would like to solve this in Django ORM level. The problem appears to me as a common design pattern however I was unable to find any examples following this structure.